# how do I put my else/if return on a web page with user prompts for values

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have written the code below. I am asking for a user prompt for the values of day
and month and I want to return their star sign based on the values that they submit.
I do not know how to get the result of their input displayed on a web page.

```
So 
user prompt for day
user prompt for month
then I want the starsign returned based on the else/if code. Can anybody help?

Thanks        
var StarSign= 
["Aries","Taurus","Gemini","Cancer","Leo","Virgo","Libra","Scorpio","Sagittarius"
"Capricorn","Aquarius","Pisces"]

function signOftheZodiac(theDay,theMonth){
var theDay=prompt("What is your day of birth");
var theMonth=prompt("What is your month of birth");
if ((theDay>=21 && theMonth=="March") || (theDay<=19 && theMonth=="April")){
return StarSign[0];

}else if ((theDay>=20 && theMonth=="April")||(theDay<=20 && theMonth=="May")){
    return StarSign[1];

}else if ((theDay>=21 && theMonth=="May")||(theDay<=20 && theMonth=="June")){
    return StarSign[2];

}else if((theDay>=21 && theMonth=="June") ||(theDay<=22 && theMonth=="July")){
return StarSign[3]

}else if((theDay>=23 && theMonth=="July")||(theDay<=22 && theMonth=="August")){
return StarSign[4]

}else if((theDay>=23 && theMonth=="August")||(theDay<=22 && theMonth=="September")){
return StarSign[5]

}else if((theDay>=23 && theMonth=="September")||(theDay<=22 && theMonth=="October")){
return StarSign[6]

}else if((theDay>=23 && theMonth=="October")||(theDay<=21 && theMonth=="November")){
return StarSign[7]

}else if((theDay>=22 && theMonth=="November")||(theDay<=21 && theMonth=="December")){
return StarSign[8]

}else if((theDay>=22 && theMonth=="December")||(theDay<=19 && theMonth=="January")){
return StarSign[9]

}else if((theDay>=20 && theMonth=="January")||(theDay<=18 && theMonth=="February")){
return StarSign[10]

}else if((theDay>=19 && theMonth=="February")||(theDay<=20 && theMonth=="March")){
result= StarSign[11]

}

var h1=document.createElement("h1")
var textAnswer=document.createTextNode("Your Star sign is")
h1.setAttribute("id","signOftheZodiac");
h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
document.getElementById("flex-child").appendChild(h1)
}
function reset(){
document.getElementById("signOftheZodiac").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't want to do this with JS-Dialogs (which are ugly). Rather use HTML-Input that you can style (and optionally hide once you calculated the sign).

Something like this: (note that I fixed minor errors in your JS where you assigned `result` instead of returning it. Hope it's useable for your purposes ;)

```js
var StarSign = ["Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius",
    "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Pisces"
  ];

  function signOftheZodiac() {
    var theDay = document.getElementById("day").value;
    var d=document.getElementById("month");
    var theMonth = d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;
;
    console.log(theDay,theMonth);
    if ((theDay >= 21 && theMonth == "March") || (theDay <= 19 && theMonth == "April")) {
      return StarSign[0];

    } else if ((theDay >= 20 && theMonth == "April") || (theDay <= 20 && theMonth == "May")) {
      return StarSign[1];

    } else if ((theDay >= 21 && theMonth == "May") || (theDay <= 20 && theMonth == "June")) {
      return StarSign[2];

    } else if ((theDay >= 21 && theMonth == "June") || (theDay <= 22 && theMonth == "July")) {
      return StarSign[3]

    } else if ((theDay >= 23 && theMonth == "July") || (theDay <= 22 && theMonth == "August")) {
      return StarSign[4]

    } else if ((theDay >= 23 && theMonth == "August") || (theDay <= 22 && theMonth == "September")) {
      return StarSign[5]

    } else if ((theDay >= 23 && theMonth == "September") || (theDay <= 22 && theMonth == "October")) {
      return StarSign[6]

    } else if ((theDay >= 23 && theMonth == "October") || (theDay <= 21 && theMonth == "November")) {
      return StarSign[7]

    } else if ((theDay >= 22 && theMonth == "November") || (theDay <= 21 && theMonth == "December")) {
      return StarSign[8]

    } else if ((theDay >= 22 && theMonth == "December") || (theDay <= 19 && theMonth == "January")) {
      return StarSign[9]

    } else if ((theDay >= 20 && theMonth == "January") || (theDay <= 18 && theMonth == "February")) {
      return StarSign[10]

    } else if ((theDay >= 19 && theMonth == "February") || (theDay <= 20 && theMonth == "March")) {
      return StarSign[11]

    }
}

function calc() {
    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("Your Star sign is " + signOftheZodiac());
    console.info(textAnswer);
    h1.setAttribute("id", "signOftheZodiac");
    h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
    document.getElementById("flex-child").appendChild(h1)
  }

  function reset() {
    document.getElementById("signOftheZodiac").remove();
  }
```

```html
<select id="month">
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<input type="number" id="day">
<button type="button" onclick="calc()">Calc</button>

<p id="flex-child"></p>
```

Comment: For a faster response, I'd recommend `var text = "Your Star sign is " + signOftheZodiac(); console.info(text); var textAnswer = document.createTextNode(text);` because `console.info(textAnswer)` noticeably locks the UI while it's outputting.

Comment: Argh - you're right. I forgiot to remove that console.info, it was purely intended for debugging.

Comment: Thanks MBaas for all your help and suggestions, I've got it working it now. There was more to do on it than I thought. Its only my second JS project so all the info was helpful, thanks also WOUNDEDStevenJones

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept my answer and close the question so that ppl won't be confused by seeing it as "open".